# Reescribir rutas PHP con HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rutas

Intento reescribir rutas con HTACCESS pero no soy capaz.
Estoy utilizando MVC y actualmente las rutas se genera del tipo http://localhost/realestate/web/index.php?ruta=escaparate

Mi idea es que queden del tipo
http://localhost/realestate/web/escaparate

Es decir omitir el index.php?ruta=

Actualmente estoy utilizando este codigo:

```
 RewriteEngine on 


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-zAZ0-9]+)$ ?ruta=$1
```

Mi codigo php para el trato de estas rutas es el siguiente:

```
 $map = array(
    'home' => array('controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'home'),
    'escaparate' => array('controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'escaparate'),
    );

//Parsing

if(isset($_GET['ruta'])){
    if(isset($map[$_GET['ruta']])){
        $ruta = $_GET['ruta'];
    }
    else{
        //404
        header('404 Not Found');
        echo '<html><body><p style color:red "><b>ERROR: No existe la ruta '. $_GET['ruta'] . '</b></p></body></html>';
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    $ruta = 'home';
}
```

Pero no lo consigo, he probado varias formas que he encontrado por aquí.
Agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: HTACCESS solo funciona en apache creo que motor para tu sitio web usas???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent utilizo apache, así es. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tienes el código

la url de entrada es por ejemplo:

```
http://localhost/realestate/web/escaparat
```

```html
RewriteEngine on 


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^realestate/web/([^/]+)/?$ /realestate/web/index.php?ruta=$1  [L,NC]
```

la url de salida sera

```
http://localhost/realestate/web/index.php?ruta=escaparat
```

Puedes probarlo [aqui](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que ese .htaccess es para localhost, seguramente cuando se suba a la web en producción habría que quitarle la ruta realstate/web/

Comment: Seguramente, todo dependerá de las carpetas o subcarpetas

Comment: Buenas tardes @WilfredoAleman , muchísimas gracias por Tus respuestas. La intención es a la inversa:
Entrada: http://localhost/realestate/web/index.php?ruta=escaparat
Salida: http://localhost/realestate/web/escaparat

He probado invirtiendo la RewriteRule, pero no funciona. Como se haría?

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Muchas gracias, por tu comentario, lo tengo en cuenta ya que a la hora de publicarlo, lo publicaré desde la carpeta raiz realestate, supongo que unicamente tendré que quitar realestate del codigo, ya que mi MVC está compuesto dentro de la raiz (realestate) por dos carpetas web y app

Comment: @AntonioRodríguez  perdona que me meta pero La entrada `localhost/realestate/web/index.php?ruta=escaparat`  no tiene sentido  ya que las URL amigables son para que el `usuario` se sienta mas comodo escribiendo en lenguaje natural

Comment: Claro @WilfredoAleman por eso lo que te comento es que mi web usa rutas del tipo no amigables que serian así 'localhost/realestate/web/index.php?ruta=escaparat', las cuales son del tipo no amigable, y yo la quiero convertir en web/escaparate que son del tipo amigable. Por lo tanto la entrada es index.php?ruta=escaparat y la salida al revés

Comment: @WilfredoAleman aprovecho para consultarte, en el caso de que yo use atributos por GET, como se realizaria para que fuera escaparate/52 en vez de index.php?ruta=escaparate&id=52.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda,

Comment: solo tendrías que agregar una line mas `RewriteRule ^realestate/web/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /realestate/web/index.php?ruta=$1&id$2  [L,NC]`

Comment: @WilfredoAleman pero me lo podrías poner para que fuera al revés la entrada como te he comentado. Te lo agradecería mucho, y ya te la marco como solucionada si editas la respuesta. – 
Antonio Rodríguez